# Separate Production Database Vs Linked Tables in Single Production Database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, soa, database-schema

first of all, I don't know if this is the right platform for this question. I hope it is. This is basically an architectural issue or more specifically a database design issue.

My company has asked me to create a service based website where individual subscribers can log in to their own customizable retail store.  One fundamental question related to this requirement is designing the database. As I can understand there are two major approaches

1. Create a separate database based on a template for each subscriber / client.
2. Have a single database for all clients and link the tables based on primary key fields.

If any one has experience with the above scenario or can provide any useful insights, please do let me know.

Regards
Romi

Comment: I would recommend reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: this is an excellent link thanks a ton! havent gone through it in detail. just glanced. but it looks really promising. Will read it in detail shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate database

- You can put them easy to a other dedicated server
- You have to administrate 1,000 databases for 1,000 clients
- Your application need to figure out which database have to be used

one database with relationships

- You have to administrate only one database
- Less additional complexity in your application (tons of configurations etc.)
- You can easy `JOIN` tables over all clients. For statistics or what ever.

Comment: Hi Edze, If i have a control table in a separate database with the client names/IDs and database names would not the administering / configuring the clients become easier?

Comment: If you change you table structure, you have to do it 1,000x times. If you make a backup or restore, you have to do it for 1,000 databases. And so on ...